# Get value with corresponding highest int with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, join, aggregate-functions

I have 2 tables:

- quests (2 columns: player, quest)
- dimension_quest (2 columns: quest, order)

[quests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHzNW.png) [dimension_quest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJQpm.png)

For all players, I'd like to have the quest with the highest "order" column. I want all 3 columns (player, quest, order)

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSeQl.png)

Note that a quest has an unique "order" value in dimension_table. I cannot really aggregate the quest strings.

What I could do is this

```
SELECT player, max(dim.order) FROM quests qu
LEFT JOIN dimension_quest dim ON qu.quest = dim.quest
GROUP BY player
```

THEN JOIN again with dimension_quest to have the quest name. But isn't there a better way to have directly the quest name in the aggregated query, instead of joining dimension_quest twice?

Comment: FYI
I'm currently using HIVE (which I probably should have mentioned before), and someone told me max(struct(dim.order, dim.quest)).col2 also does the job.

Comment: It works only because for each dim.order, there's a unique dim.quest.
I don't know how max(struct(...)) would work if a dim_order value could be associated to multiple dim_quest values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But isn't there a better way to have directly the quest name in the aggregated query, instead of joining dimension_quest twice?

No.  In standard SQL, the selection list for an aggregate query may refer only to grouping columns and aggregate functions of the groups.  Your `quest` columns are neither.

Some SQL dialects allow other columns to be selected in aggregate queries, but those dialects generally do not specify from which row of each group the corresponding values for such columns will be selected.  That's ok in some cases, but it is not sufficient for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it without an extra join using `row_number()`.

```
select  player, quest, "order"
from    (
        select  player, q.quest, "order"
                ,row_number() over(partition by player order by "order" desc) as rn
        from    quests q join dimension_quest dq on dq.quest = q.quest
        ) t
where   rn = 1
```

| player | quest | order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | Mission2 | 3 |
| peter | Mission1 | 2 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/M9n1nLnt)

Comment: I'm guessing using row_number() is a bit costly computation-wise, like an extra JOIN ; but this solution is nice to keep in mind. Thanks! (also didn't know fiddle, it's a neat tool!)

Comment: Row-number should be much faster than an extra join. Especially with big data